# How to centre element within a viewport?

Tags: css, html

I have the following HTML code where each scene div is a set width and floated left.
I would like the entire `.section_2` block to be centred within the view port, regardless of screen dimensions:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="scroller">
    <section class="section_2">
      <div class="scene2B1" data-stellar-ratio="1.1"></div>
      <div class="scene2B2" data-stellar-ratio="1.4"></div>
      <div class="scene2B3" data-stellar-ratio="1.3"></div>
      <div class="scene2B4" data-stellar-ratio="1.5"></div>
      <div class="scene2B5" data-stellar-ratio="1.2"></div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS.

```
.section_2 { margin: 0 auto; width: 800px; }
```

Note: You MUST set a width.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set div#wrapper to position itself at the center of the viewport it is important that you do one of the following:

1. Know what the exact width and height of the div#wrapper will be
2. Use javascript to dynamically modify the height and the width of div#wrapper based on the users viewport

I'll give you sample code for option #1 (Option #2 is the same except add the javascript to dynamically resize div#wrapper)

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="scroller">
      <section class="section_2">
        <div class="scene2B1" data-stellar-ratio="1.1"></div>
        <div class="scene2B2" data-stellar-ratio="1.4"></div>
        <div class="scene2B3" data-stellar-ratio="1.3"></div>
        <div class="scene2B4" data-stellar-ratio="1.5"></div>
        <div class="scene2B5" data-stellar-ratio="1.2"></div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div#wrapper {
  width: 300px; /* Must define this */
  height: 300px; /* Must define this */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -150px /* This is HALF of the height times -1 */
  margin-left: -150px /* This is HALF of the width times -1 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time the way @SMacFadyen gave will work, but if it doesn't (and I haven't figured why it doesn't sometimes), you can try:

```
    .section_2 {
         margin-left:400px;/* half the width*/
         left:-50%;
         width: 800px;
    }
```

As with the other answer, you must set a width. It does seem to be somewhat of a hack but it works for me.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/EfSBA/1/z

To center it in the entire viewport instead of just the parent element, you can try:

```
     position:fixed;
```

but this can have some subtle side effects, so make sure it is what you want